# C# could not create ssl/tls secure channel (Restsharp)

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2, restsharp

I'm currently trying to connect to an api but I am getting this error:
`could not create ssl/tls secure channel`

The request works when its made through `Postman`, same endpoint, same certificate and everything, but when I am making the request through restsharp it stops with the SSL/TLS error

I've tried forcing the security protocol to TLS12 with the code:
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Also tried to remove the certificate validation with
`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };`
And some other variations of this code.

Tried to disable it on the client as well, with no success either
`client.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`

So I am currently trying to use `Wireshark` to get some more information. From what i could understand, it isn't an issue with the cipher suite, since it passes the "Client Hello" and "Server Hello" and it stops on the "Certificate Request, Server Hello Done".

[image: Wireshark 1]

The errors that appear on the image also appear when I make the request with Postman.

It stops on this line when it receives a `RST` flag with the `ACK`.

[image: Wireshark 2]

Does anyone have any idea on why it isn't working?

Also it's worth mentioning that I used the same code many times before to call other api's and they seem to work fine. Just this one that I can't make work no matter what I try. I don't have access to the servers since its a third-party api.

Any help on this matter is appreciated.

Edit: To add the code that i use to make the api call and some more info that was asked

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificateReturn, chainReturn, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

var client = new RestClient(api);
client.Timeout = -1;

//Add Certificate
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
if (GCONTABANCO.SelectCERTIFICADO(IDCONTABANCO, ref cert, ref MSG) == false) { return false; }
client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
client.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);
request.AddParameter("scope", "extrato.read boleto-cobranca.read boleto-cobranca.write");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I'm using .net framework 4.5.2, i tried updating to 4.7 but the error persisted and currently i can't update the version because its a big system and can't risk breaking it

Windows build number: 21H1 (10.0.19043)

Comment: "i used the same code" what code, you haven't shown any? Which exact build number of .NET and which eaxct build number of Windows? If Wireshark cannot read the packet then it's probably corrupt, so it that is what's coming from the server then you need to speak to whoever runs it. Alternatively, a little googling indicates it might be a bug in Wireshark, are you on the latest version? Possibly relevant Wireshark bug https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/18130

Comment: @Charlieface editted the question with the info that you asked. I'm on the latest version of wireshark, downloaded it on the same day. I think its just a bug with wireshark that doesn't seem to impact the connection to the server, since when i run wireshark and make a postman call the bug still appears but doesn't receive a RST flag

Comment: The exception should have an `InnerException` which has more detail. I would say upgrade to 4.7.2 at least, and remove `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ...` line. I agree Wireshark is probably just a bug, but the packet it is erroring on is the one we need. The RST packet is not directly relevant: we need to know *why* a RST was sent, *why* was the connection closed. It might also be the opposite: the API might not support newer protocols.

Comment: @Charlieface unfortunatelly it doesn't have an InnerException in the Exception, it's just null. The exception just returns a `could not create ssl/tls secure channel` and i tried using trace log to see if i get anything else but just got a message from InitializeSecurityContext saying that it returned `code=IllegalMessage`, which isn't much. I'm not sure if it could be my ip getting blocked on their end since requests made through postman work just fine, i'll still try contacting them to see if it is some configuration on their side.

Comment: `IllegalMessage` makes me think something is mucking up the TLS connection, possibly a transparent enterprise firewall or similar. WIthout a working Wireshark trace it's hard to say for sure. Another thing to check: the server might want the whol `X509Chain` ffrom the client, rather than just the certificate.

Comment: @Charlieface i think it's something on that specific url they are using, i made some tests trying to connect to a different url that they use to call the api methods and has the same requirements as this one, it somehow works fine, so i think it's something that they configured to this specific url. I'm currently trying to get their help on this issue, but they take a long time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to fix the issue with the help from their IT architect, i'll leave the answer here in case someone runs into the same issue in the future.

Since they had a lot of certificates being sent through the connection, it was going over the limit allowed and closing the connection, so i had to change the limit to be able to connect to the server. In C# it has to be changed on the regedit.

To do so i had to:

- Open regedit.
- Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Messaging
- Then add a MessageLimitClient DWORD value.
- Set the value to 65536.
- Restart the machine.

After doing that and testing again the connection was successful.